# How can I create backup script for selected tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-backups, windows-scripting

I am using below script to create backup file but it takes backup of all tables. I want backup of selected tables. how can I achieve this.

`imp <username>/<password>@<hostname> file=<filename>.dmp log=<filename>.log full=y;`

Below script is working fine.
`select 'C:\Daily-MIS-Backup\'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD-HH24MISS')||'.DMP' foo3 from dual; HOST EXP USERID=myusername/mypassFILE='^LOG1' GRANTS=Y ROWS=Y OWNER=SMPSYS LOG=EXPORT.LOG`

We tried following code but it took backup of all tables. we need backup of selected tables.
 `select 'C:\Daily-MIS-Backup\'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD-HH24MISS')||'.DMP' foo3 from dual; HOST EXP USERID=myusername/mypassFILE='^LOG1' GRANTS=Y ROWS=Y OWNER=SMPSYS LOG=EXPORT.LOG`

Answer (score 2):

The `import` and `export` utilities have a `TABLES` parameter.  Syntax is like this:

```
 TABLES=(myschema1.table1, myschema2.table2, ...)
```

Remember to escape the parentheses if you're on UNIX or an OS that requires that.